# Setting up Mercury Mail Server to require authentication for non-local mail only and not local mail

Tags: email, authentication, localhost, mail-server

Is it possible to configure Mercury Mail Server to require authentication to send mail from a non-local address(anything but localhost or 127.0.0.1) but *not* require authentication to send from localhost(the php mail function for a locally hosted website, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, turn on authentication for MercuryS and then in connection control setup 127.0.0.1 to allow relaying.

From the help:

If you check the Connections may relay through this server control, Mercury will use this as part of the process it applies to determine whether or not a specific connection can relay mail.

That said you may be opening up Mercury as an open relay when using 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it.  In case anyone else is experiencing a similar issue, be sure to select "Authenticated SMTP connections may relay mail" and _not_ the last option, "Only Authenticated ..."